# Updating extra data on notification intents on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

I am unable to update extra data included in notification action (line 34 of `MainActivity.kt`). If I make several notifications and click the action button on them, the extra data that was included on the first notification is always delivered (line 16 of `NotificationBroadcastReceiver.kt`).

The value is printed on log on line 33 of `MainActivity.kt` and line 17 of `NotificationBroadcastReceiver.kt`.

This happens even after clearing the notifications and killing the app from task manager. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app, will help making the update once.

[Notification Action Demo](https://github.com/JarmoKukkola/androidNotificationActionDemo)

from MainActivity.kt

```
  fun notify(v:View) {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val mBuilder = NotificationCompat
        .Builder(this,this.localClassName)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_default)
        .addAction(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float,"test",getSnoozePendingIntent(time))
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(time.toInt(),mBuilder.build())
  }

  private fun getSnoozePendingIntent(time:Long):PendingIntent {
    val snoozeIntent = Intent(this,NotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    Log.d("TimeMillis before",time.toString())
    snoozeIntent.putExtra(NotificationBroadcastReceiver.timeTag,time)
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,snoozeIntent,0)
  }
```

from NotificationBroadcastReceiver.kt

```
  override fun onReceive(context:Context,intent:Intent) {
    val time = intent.getLongExtra(timeTag,0)
    Log.d("TimeMillis after",time.toString())
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel(time.toInt())
  }
```

Comment: please post the relevant parts of your code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `requestCode` if you plan to have multiple pending intents: "int: Private request code for the sender"

```
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, 0)
```

To:

```
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, uniqueCode++, snoozeIntent, 0)
```

OR:
set `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to update an individual pending intent: "Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent."

```
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: Wow, what an inefficient use of memory. Kind of makes you wonder, what's hanging around in the android system memory stacks. Anyway, probably should only use integers that refer to runtime values, since android is a garbage junkie.

Comment: Or actually just use this one: PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT. WHICH SHOULD BE THE DEFAULT [HINT ANDROID-DEVELOPERS]. No sane coder in their correct mind would anticipate a cached request, result, when new data has been added to the data container that is sent to a remote object, unless there was some reference to a cache somewhere in the api language.

Comment: [InfinitelyPendingIntent LOL, and that's the default, LOL]